# How to ensure replaceAll will replace a whole word and not a subString

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I have an input of dictionary. The dictionary is iterated over to replace the `key` from dictionary in the text. But `replaceAll` function replaces the `subString` as well.

How to ensure that it will match the whole word (as a whole and not as a `subString`)

```
String text= "Synthesis of 1-(2,6-dimethylbenzyl)-1H-indole-6-carboxylic acid [69-3] The titled compound (883 mg) sdvfshd[69-3]3456 as a white solid was prepared"

dictionary= {[69-3]=1-(2,6-dimethylbenzyl)-1H-indole-6-carboxylic acid }

for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : dictionary.entrySet()){

        text=text.replaceAll("\\b"+Pattern.quote(entry.getKey())+"\\b", entry.getValue());

}
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the elements for `equal` before replacing?

Comment: I didnt get the question..what do u mean by equal??? I am using entire text to replace and havent tokenised it..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`replaceAll` takes as parameter a regular expression.

In regular expressions, you have [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) : `\b` (use `\\b` in a string literal). They're the best way to ensure you're matching a word and not a part of a word : `"\\bword\\b"`

But in your case, you can't use word boundaries as you're not looking for a word (`[69-3]` isn't a word).

I suggest this :

```
text=text.replaceAll("(?=\\W+|^)"+Pattern.quote("[69-3]")+"(?=\\W+|$)", ...
```

The idea is to match a string end or something that's not a word. I can't ensure this will be the right solution for you though : such a pattern must be tuned knowing the exact complete use case.

Note that if all your keys follow a similar pattern there might be a better solution than to iterate through a dictionary, you might for example use a pattern like `"(?=\\W+|^)\\[\\d+\\-\\d+\\](?=\\W+|$)"`.

Comment: I am using Pattern.quote to keep the special characters intact. but even that doesnt work. also I have tried \\b .. it doesnt work

Comment: @user2832203 Please write down in your question the code which doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

"\bword\b" is working for me.

Sample Code :

```
for (row <- df.rdd.collect){   
var config_key = row.mkString(",").split(",")(0)
var config_value = row.mkString(",").split(",")(1)
val rc_applied_hiveQuery="select * from emp_details_Spark2 where empid_details= 'empid' limit 10"
var str_row = rc_applied_hiveQuery.replaceAll("\\b"+config_key+"\\b", "xyz")
println(str_row)}
```

Output : select * from emp_details_Spark2 where empid_details= '5' limit 10